# Segmentation fault after returning an aligned structure

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, clang

The minimal instance of my problem that I came up with is as follows:

```
struct __attribute__((aligned(16))) Foo {
    float x, y, z;
    Foo(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

class Bar {
public:
    Foo foo;

    Bar(const Foo &foo) : foo(foo) {}
    Foo bar() { return foo; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar *bar = new Bar(Foo(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    bar->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code results in segmentation fault when run if compiled with `clang++` (version 3.4, the default one available in Ubuntu 14.04). The problem does not occur when I compile this with `g++` (version 4.8.4). Is this a compiler bug or is there some problem with my code?

As a side note: the program does not crash if `bar` is stack-allocated, i.e.:

```
Bar bar(Foo(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
bar.bar();
```

works as intended.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you `delete bar;` before exit?

Comment: @BarışUşaklı: Nope. The problem is precisely with the `return foo;` statement. If I replace it with, for example, `return Foo(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` the problem is gone.

Comment: Raise it as a bug on the appropriate bug site? This is not a bug reporting venue.

Comment: Tried with std::alignas ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I will, I just wanted to know whether this is a compiler bug or a misuse of C++.

Comment: A look at the generated asm code might provide some insight.  So far as I understand, it looks like a compiler bug.  But I'm not a language lawyer, so I can't be sure it is a compiler bug.  If there were some language obscurity we are overlooking, the generated code might provide the hint to see what we are overlooking.

Comment: Compiled with `clang++` 3.5 works fine.

Comment: @user58697: I have just tried with `clang++` 3.5 and 3.6, both cause a segmentation fault for me. I run on 32-bit system though, perhaps that matters.

Comment: Can you post the assembly code that clang generates from your program?

Comment: is there any name hiding from "Bar(const Foo &foo) : foo(foo)" ??? foo has the same name as Bar::foo.

Comment: compiled with gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2 works fine. 
compiled with Visual Studio 2010 (and __declspec(align(16))), works fine.
==> Compiler bug in clang 3.4? I dont have a clang version that old lying around here. :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess that stack based version gets aligned ok by luck. Adding a U8 before instruction could make the stack different so you can test it.
When you place it on heap it gets random :-)
There's a chance you experienced bug in code generation as Probably your 32bit values got aligned on 16bit boundaries and code has been generated for unaligned access. X86 would silently handle this exception but not for floats. That's also worth to try -change to ints.